# R iterate over columns dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to apply statistics to the columns of a dataframe in an iterated fashion:

columns number 1: 'A' represents the tags that I want to discriminate:

```
for (i in names(dataframe)) {
    i <- as.name(i)
    group1 <- i[A=="locationX"]
    group2 <- i[A!="locationX"]
    p <- wilcox.test(group1,group2,na.action(na.omit))$p.value
}
```

however, the `as.name()` is to try to remove the inverted commas from the column names generated by `names(dataframe)`.

Unfortunately it gives me the error:

> Error in i[A == "locationX"] : 
>     object of type 'symbol' is not subsettable

I think `as.name()` is not the right way to do it.

Any clues?

Comment: can you please give an example `A`, and also perhaps `head(dataframe)` (which just gives us a look at your dataframe)?

Answer (score 12):

The only way this makes sense if for "A" to be a vector with multiple instances of "locationX" *and* multiple instance of the converse *and* for the length of "A" to be the same as the number of rows in "dataframe". If that is the case then something like this might work:

```
p <- list()
for (i in names(dataframe)) {
   # using as.names not needed and possibly harmful
    group1 <- dataframe[[i]][A == "locationX"]
    group2 <- dataframe[[i]][A != "locationX"]
    p[i] <- wilcox.test(group1,group2,na.action(na.omit))$p.value
}
```

Note that even if you did not get an error with your code that you would still have been overwriting the "p" every time through the loop.